# Track radio input state React

Tags: reactjs, forms, radio-button, jsx

Here is my Radiobutton component:

```
export default class Radiobutton extends PureComponent {
  render() {
    const { answer, value } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className="form">
        <div className="form__answer">
          <FormGroup check>
            <Label check>
              <Input type="radio" name="radio" value={value} />
              {answer}
              <span className="checkmark" />
            </Label>
          </FormGroup>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And the component where I use it in:

```
class RadiobuttonQuestion extends PureComponent {
  render() {
    const { title, question, answers } = this.props.question;
    return (
      <div>
        <Question title={title} question={question} />
        <Form>
          {answers.map(answer => (
            <Radiobutton key={answer._id} answer={answer.value} />
          ))}
          <SubmitButton />
        </Form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I'm trying to track the state of the question and the answers, to send data about which option was chosen by the user.

I've tried different options but overall it's not totally clear for me if I should set the state for the Radiobutton or for the RadiobuttonQuestion? It seems more logical to do it in the Question, because when I tried it in the button, since I did an onClick event, the state kept changing not according to which radio button was chosen, the 3 buttons don't know about each other at this point.

So if I could do a console.log about the chosen one, that would be a start.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

**RadioButton**

```
const RadioButton = ({ answer, value, name }) => (
  <label>
    <input 
      type="radio" 
      name={name} 
      value={value}
    />
    {answer}
  </label>
)
```

**RadioGroup**

```
const RadioButtonAnswers = ({answers, chooseAnswer, name}) => (
  <div onChange={chooseAnswer}>
   { answers.map(props => ( 
     <RadioButton key={props.value} {...props} name={name} />)
   )}
  </div> 
)
```

**Question**

```
class Question extends React.Component {
    state = {
    answer: ""
  }

  chooseAnswer = e => this.setState({answer: e.target.value});

  render() {
    return (
        <div className="question">
          <h2>{this.props.question} --> {this.state.answer || "Not Answered"}</h2>
        <RadioButtonAnswers 
          {...this.props}
          chooseAnswer={this.chooseAnswer}
        />
        </div>
    )
  }
}
```

**App**

```
class App extends React.Component {
    state = {
    questions: [
    {
      "name": "q1",
      "question": "A dog goes?",
      "answers": [
        {value: "woof", answer: "Woof!"},
        {value: "meow", answer: "Meoooowwwwwww!"},
        {value: "quack", answer: "Quack! Quack!"}
            ]
    },
        {
      "name": "q2",
      "question": "A Cat goes?",
      "answers": [
        {value: "meow", answer: "Meoooowwwwwww!"},
        {value: "tweet", answer: "Tweet! Tweet!"},
        {value: "moo", answer: "MOOOOOOOO!"}
            ]
    }]
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Questions:</h2>
        <div>
          {this.state.questions.map((item, index) => (
            <Question 
              key={index} 
              {...item}
             />
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

**Dom binding**

```
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="app"></div>
```